# Building Bitmaps From Characters

Tags: c#, bitmap

Is there a way I can build a bitmap strictly from RGB values for each pixel? I'm trying to build a bitmap from a string of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327164%28VS.71%29.aspx) to construct the pixel color from your text file, and [`Bitmap.SetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel.aspx) to set the pixel color for that pixel position in the bitmap.